# Installer doesn't recognize kingston SSDnow sv 200 90g

Tags: 12.04, ssd, ubuntu-studio

I'm trying install Ubuntu 12.04 on my new Kingston SSD Now SVP200S3/90G, but the installer doesn't list this disk to be installed. However gparted let me do any partitioning operation correctly.

I've tryed with Ubuntu Studio and Ubuntu Desktop on different machines: Lenovo ThinkPad T400, Lenovo ThinkStation C20, MoBo ASUS Crosshair V formula. SATA controller in all machines has been set to AHCI and IDE operation and different SATA ports with no luck.

The firmware on the SSD has been updated to V.503xxx (latest on kingston page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a problem with the factory written partition table on USB sticks.  The problem shows up as the device not being available to Ubiquity or Startup Disk Creator to make a bootable disk and the partition table can not be deleted in Gparted.

Perhaps this is the same problem but with an SSD.  The solution might be the same: to erase the partition table directly and to write a new one with Gparted.  Open a terminal window and type:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1
```

Change X to the correct device (a,b,c etc) but be *quite* certain you have the correct device as there will be nothing left on the drive to look at after you press enter.

You will then need to create the partition table on the device with Gparted, then make the partitions that you want.  Chris

Comment: Thanks Chris for your response, I did that via disk tools on a OSX operating system, thanks to this response now I know how to do it via command line.